# SocketError: sockaddr resolved to multiple nodename

Tags: ruby

ruby build is failing with error make spec failing, Any input on this will be useful

I am using

```
Build language: c
Build dist: bionic
Build id: 764199404
Job id: 764199405
Runtime kernel version: 5.4.0-1032-gcp
travis-build version: 091d532a
Build image provisioning date and time
Mon Dec 28 15:53:02 UTC 2020
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

Part source where issue is observed

```
platform_is_not :windows do
        describe 'using NI_NUMERICHOST as the flag' do
          it 'returns an Array containing the numeric hostname and service name' do
            Socket.getnameinfo(@addr, Socket::NI_NUMERICHOST).should == [ip_address, 'ftp']
          end
        end
      end
```

```
Socket.getnameinfo using IPv4 using a 3 element Array as the first argument using NI_NUMERICHOST as the flag returns an Array containing the numeric hostname and service name ERROR
SocketError: sockaddr resolved to multiple nodename
/home/travis/build/alpha/ruby/spec/ruby/library/socket/socket/getnameinfo_spec.rb:111:in `getnameinfo'
/home/travis/build/alpha/ruby/spec/ruby/library/socket/socket/getnameinfo_spec.rb:111:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/travis/build/alpha/ruby/spec/ruby/library/socket/socket/getnameinfo_spec.rb:65:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: What was the exact command you ran to build? Which version of ruby? How did you configure the build?

Comment: Build on master branch, Configurated using command export SETARCH='setarch i686 --verbose --3gb'  $SETARCH ../configure -C --disable-install-doc --prefix=$RUBY_PREFIX $CONFIG_FLAG and built with command: $SETARCH make -s $JOBS